# How can read_cifar10() routine return anything other than first object in TensorFlow tutorial?

Tags: python, tensorflow

TensorFlow has CIFAR-10 tutorial, which [is discussed here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#convolutional-neural-networks). Source code in Python [is here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/0.6.0/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10).

It has [read_cifar10() routine here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0.6.0/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py), which is intended to read samples from binary file.

I am failing to understand, how it works. Suspect this is somehow related with TensorFlow deferred nature, but can't figure out how.

At some point routine does the following:

```
# Read a record, getting filenames from the filename_queue.  No
  # header or footer in the CIFAR-10 format, so we leave header_bytes
  # and footer_bytes at their default of 0.
  reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_bytes)
  result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
```

I see here, that a new reader is created from scratch, and then this reader is pointed to filename queue.

How many samples is returned by `read` call?

Later, inside `distorted_inputs()` method a code does following:

```
print ('Filling queue with %d CIFAR images before starting to train. '
         'This will take a few minutes.' % min_queue_examples)

  # Generate a batch of images and labels by building up a queue of examples.
  return _generate_image_and_label_batch(float_image, read_input.label,
                                         min_queue_examples)
```

Here `print` is normal Python call, not deferred, so comment assume that fetching of 20000 records will occur immediately.

How can it happen? Everywhere I see only per-one-record logic. How it multiplies on many records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; `reader.read` only adds a `read` operation to computation graph, the actual execution happens during `session.run` which is done by a separate thread in a `while(True): session.run(...)` kind of loop initiated by `start_queue_runners`

Long version:
This is part of an "input pipeline" which is complicated by the fact that reading/prefetching needs to happen asynchronously to avoid blocking. Official how-to describing input pipelines is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/how_tos/reading_data/index.html).

To be more specific, `reader.read` adds an operation to read a single record to computation graph. This operation then feeds into [`shuffle_batch`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L120) created inside `_generate_image_and_label_batch`. To this point no reading has taken place. The `shuffle_batch` operation creates a queue which decouples the input flow, in a sense that evaluation of the part of the graph before the queue and after the queue can be done asynchronously using different `session.run` calls, with queue providing buffering in the middle. Additionally `shuffle_batch` operation registers operations feeding into the queue as part of `GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS` collection.

Inside `train()`, operation `tf.start_queue_runners` will create several threads corresponding to enqueue operations registered in `GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS` collection and start evaluating them in a loop. Results of `reader.read` will flow through other ops until reaching `shuffle_batch` queue and getting saved in its memory buffer.

The part of the graph after `shuffle_batch` will get driven by the main Python thread, initiated by `sess.run([train_op, loss])` command. The thread will get a collect a batch of examples saved on the `shuffle_batch` queue and propagate it forward.

Here's an example of feeding your input queue manually instead of using queue runners.

```
queue_dtype = np.int32
queue_capacity = 2
values_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=queue_capacity, dtypes=queue_dtype)
size_op = values_queue.size()
value_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=queue_dtype)
enqueue_op = values_queue.enqueue(value_placeholder)
dequeue_op = values_queue.dequeue()
close_op = values_queue.close()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

# add two elements onto the queue
sess.run([enqueue_op], {value_placeholder:2})
sess.run([enqueue_op], {value_placeholder:3})
# if you uncomment the next line, you'll hang because queue is full
# sess.run([enqueue_op], {value_placeholder:4})

# close the queue. This means 3rd read will throw OutOfRangeError instead of
# hanging until queue is replenished
sess.run([close_op])
print('queue has %d/%d entries' % (sess.run([size_op])[0], queue_capacity))

# take two elements off the queue
fancy_computation = tf.square(dequeue_op)
print('Computation result %d' %(sess.run([fancy_computation])[0]))
print('queue has %d/%d entries' % (sess.run([size_op])[0], queue_capacity))
print('Computation result %d' %(sess.run([fancy_computation])[0]))
print('queue has %d/%d entries' % (sess.run([size_op])[0], queue_capacity))
print('Computation result %d' %(sess.run([fancy_computation])[0]))
print('queue has %d/%d entries' % (sess.run([size_op])[0], queue_capacity))
```

What you should see if you run it

```
queue has 2/2 entries
Computation result 4
queue has 1/2 entries
Computation result 9
queue has 0/2 entries
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OutOfRangeError
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can `shuffle_batch` ask `reader.read` to advance record number? What if I pass constant tensors to `shuffle_batch`?

Comment: Also, how the output of `shuffle_batch` know when it is time to generate new batch?

Comment: The queue runner thread will call the enqueue ops in an infinite loop, so it'll keep calling reader.read (or tf.constant) filling the queue with results until queue buffer gets full. When you call dequeue op (ie, by doing session run that requires result of shuffle_batch), it'll remove some elements from the queue so the other thread can start pushing elements on to the queue again

Comment: Will queue runner analyze the graph and find, that it's sources (inputs) are queues? And if it find that sources are constant tensors, what it will do? Can I simulate such enqueue behavior myself? For example, I have complex file format (like Matlab, but not only) which I can read by-record with Python, but I can't read this file with binary primitives, provided by tensorflow (because format is unknown/complex). How to feed queue with these values from python? Is it explained somewhere around here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#QueueRunner

Comment: A "queue_runner" is a thin wrapper around a python thread to call "enqueue" ops of the queue in an loop. It's created when the queue is created (shuffle_batch) and the thread is started by "start_queue_runners" . This is mostly covered in the Queues HowTo -- https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the other side -- `read`. How `read` remembers it's position and knows that it is time to increment? The only way to advance state I found -- is an `assign` op, which is not documented and mentioned only in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/get_started/basic_usage.html Somewhere inside `read` it should contain `update = tf.assign(state, new_value)`, but this op should be called explicitly. How queue runner could know it should run it???

Comment: In other words, it is described everywhere, how to implement PUSH, but nowhere -- how to implement PULL, like writing your own reader (without extending `ReaderBase` and `C++`). For example, I have a python reading function -- how to implement pulling with it, like `reader` does?

Comment: reader.read is a stateful op, it uses input_buffer which remembers it's current position -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/text_line_reader_op.cc#L61

Comment: I've added example of adding elements onto the queue manually. Use this  pattern if you want to produce your input elements from Python.

Comment: Sorry for long discussion, but to end: am I correct thinking it is IMpossible to make stateful ops/graphs without `C++`? Every graph in TF is either stateless if used ops are stateless, or state change should be executed explicitly, like with `assign`? In other words it is impossible to read MAT files in the same way it was done in CIFAR example?

Comment: You can have state by using TensorFlow variables. For instance you can have an op which returns some value and increments a variable counter during each read using a control dependency. But I see a problem when I read "implement your own reader with python reading function." TensorFlow ops are C++ and to mix C++/Python on the graph you'll need to use the feed_dict mechanism to feed the output of Python into the graph.